# AppendText method in C# (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, linq, file, appendtext

I am trying to learn C# and ADO.NET using this book: '`Accesing Data with Microsoft .NET Framework 4`' by `Glenn Johnson`. In the third chapter, '`Introducing to LINQ`', there is this code snippet:

```
foreach (var color in results)
{
    txtLog.AppendText(color + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Since there are no details of how to create the txtLog file, I tried to do it this way:

```
StreamWriter txtLog=File.CreateText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),"txtLog.txt"));
            foreach (var color in results)
                txtLog=File.AppendText(color + Environment.NewLine);
```

The problem is Environment.NewLine throws me an error: 'Illegal charactes in path'. After that, I learned that AppendText method takes as argument a path, which pretty much confuses me. How am I supposed to make the code from the book work? The snippet is used multiple times. Thanks.

Comment: `File.AppendText` does not use `txtLog`, try `txtLog.WriteLine` instead.

Comment: Are you looking for [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143357.aspx) - "Appends the specified string to the file, creating the file if it does not already exist."

Comment: I read ahead and from a point, `txtLog.Writeline` is used instead. But what's with `txt.AppendText`? Why is it used like that? Or it's just a mistake someone forgot to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you use Windows Forms you can create a new TextBox with the name txtLog. You can see [here how to create one](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/textbox-in-C-Sharp/).

Then your code will execute just fine without other modifications.

Comment: Your suggestion did solve the problem. But for the `Environment.NewLine` to work, a `RichTextBox` must be used instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a FileStream to create/append to the file, then a StreamWriter to write to that stream. For example:

```
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\Path\\FileName.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Your message");
        }
    }
```

This will create the file if it doesn't exist & append to it if it does exist.